# PDF of a transformed random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics

i have the   function   $t(Θ)=4/(4+C*cos(θ)+D*(cos(θ))^2))^2 $ the  θ  follow    the uniform distridbution  i want to find the   pdf of  τ
Αccording to theory  the  pdf of t is  $f(t)=(\frac{1}{|\frac{dt}{dθ}|})*g(θ)$  where  g(θ)=1/(π/2-0)=2/π

the  $dt/dθ=4*(C*sin(θ)+2*D*sin(θ)*cos(θ))/(4+C*cos(θ)+D*(cos(θ))^2))^2$
the    the   cos (θ)  have two solution  $cos(θ)=-C*t+sqrt(t*( (C^2-16*D)*t+16D )/(2*D*t)$

$cos(θ)=-C*t-\sqrt{t*( (C^2-16*D)*t+16D  }/(2*D*t)$  $C>0$  ι keep the fisrt  beacause the  0<θ<π/2 and  cosθ>0

the limit of  t is   $ t1<t<t2$  where  $ t1=16D/((2*D+C)^2-(C^2-16*D))$  and   $t2=1$

My  results  are  correct ?

Thnak yoy George

Comment: This site is for Q&A concerning the software application Mathematica and the Wolfram Language. If you are not using the Mathematica application, perhaps you meant to post on the [`Mathematics StackExchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: To have this question reopened you'll need to write things in terms of what you've tried with *Mathematica* code (much like @user64494 's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Something can be done numerically when specifying parameters in such a way ($C$ and $D$ are reserved in WL, so these are replaced by `c` and `d`. ).

```
c = 1; d = -8; trd = TransformedDistribution[4/(4 + c*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
d*Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^2, \[Theta] \[Distributed]UniformDistribution[{0, Pi/2}]];
Table[{x, Evaluate[CDF[trd, x]]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.05}];
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image]

Some comments: the above picture confirms that `trd` takes arbitrary values greater than or equal to approximately `0.2` in this case; Mathematica fails with PDF even numerically.